# Qual a melhor forma de utilizar notifications no Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

Estou utilizando o evento **Registered** do próprio Laravel (*Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered*) para disparar um listener que criei para disparar um email de boas vindas.

Veja como ficou o Listener:

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

// instância do evento registered do próprio Laravel
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use App\Notifications\EnviarEmailBoasVindasNotification;

class EnviarEmailBoasVindas
{
    use Notifiable;
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  NovoUsuario  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(Registered $event)
    {
        // No "envelope" $event podemos acessar a instância User assim $event->user
        $event->user->notify(new EnviarEmailBoasVindasNotification($event));
    }
}
```

Minha dúvida fica por conta de "**use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable**" e pela ocorrência "**use Notifiable**" já dentro da classe. Qual a utilidade destas? Pelo que vi se retirar ambas tudo continuará funcionando normalmente.

Comment: Tem alguma coisa que não bate no seu código, porque, esses `namespace` e `traits` possa ser não exigido ai, mas, pode ser exigido na classe dentro do método `notify`. Você seguiu a documentação eu fez outra coisa?

Comment: Tudo correto, a principio segui a documentação conforme deveria ser. Veja se estou correto, $event possui uma instância da model User, dentro desta model eu tenho a ocorrência **use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;**, seria este o motivo pelo qual não preciso ter uma nova ocorrência no arquivo acima?

Comment: Aonde você chama `EnviarEmailBoasVindas`?

Comment: Tenho um event que chama esse listener (EnviarEmailBoasVindas) aí.

Comment: eu faria uma `notification` e um `observers`? eu acho que fica mais lógico.

Comment: De fato Virgilio, neste caso é melhor utilizar observers. Não conhecia essa opção. Porém, acredito que no caso acima, meu entendimento esteja correto ao imaginar que não preciso instanciar novamente a classe notification já que está é instanciada na model User

Comment: Eu não consigui entender o que você fez porque eu já fiz isso e tenho exemplos e precisa sim, pelo que pude perceber ou imagina tem duas classes uma chamando a outra! bom é suposição. mas, no seu caso é melhor um observer com método created com notification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente, você precisa entender o que está usando ao fazer a utilização de `use Notifiable`.

Isso trata-se de um `trait`. Um `trait` em PHP é um mecanismo de reutilização de código que visa resolver problemas de herança de métodos.

Com um `trait`, você pode escrever algo como se fosse "um pedaço" da classe e herdar em várias outras classes.

Foi isso que o Laravel fez. Isso que você está usando é um `trait` que possui alguns métodos para facilitar a utilização da sua notificação.

O `trait` Notifiable herda outros dois traits: `HasDatabaseNotifications` e `RoutesNotifications`. Eles possuem vários métodos.

Para você poder notar a diferença, bastaria fazer assim:

```
print_r(get_class_methods(new App\Listeners\EnviarEmailBoasVindas));
```

Isso vai exibir todos os métodos da sua classe. Você debuga usando o `use Notificable`, depois debuga sem. Vai notar que os métodos são adicionados na sua classe.

## Conclusão

Se você não está utilizando nenhum dos métodos de `Notifiable`, realmente não é necessário herdá-lo. Use caso necessitar.

Há casos onde os traits são colocados para manter o comportamento padrão do Framework, como no caso dos traits de autenticação (depois eu coloco um exemplo pra você entender melhor).

Comment: Muito bom, bela explicação. Agora compreendi.